# mongodb storing data in local time, even though input is in UTC

Tags: c#, mongodb, azure-functions

So we're inserting data in this format. You can see that the ISO date is in UTC format with the Z for Zulu.

[image]

However when we retrieve it from Mongo, it's reading as local time (GMT -7).

[image]

Why aren't isn't my timezone format being observed? We're using the C# Libraries for MongoDB.

Comment: The time is stored as UTC time, however your tool displays it as local time. Usually you can set this in the user preferences of the tool, at least in Studio 3T I can set this. Read the data with native tool like the `mongo` shell, it will show the raw data as stored in DB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set in the tool options, here are a few examples:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Yes thanks, that was quite helpful! Very confusing if you don't know what to look for.